# Auto append prefix to tcolorbox's title

Tags: conditionals, tcolorbox, frame-title

I would like to have a `tcolorbox` environment that appends the prefix "Note:" to the given title.  Thus, using the option

```
title={My Title}
```

to this environment would produce a title of `Note: My Title`.

One way to achieve this is to have the environment accept two parameters. The first being the usual `tcolorbox` options, the second being the title. This is what the `MyNoteX` environment in the MWE below does. However, I dislike this as the interface to it is no longer similar to the other `tcolorbox`s that I have.

### Question:

How do I modify the `MyNote` environment so that it produces the same title as the `MyNoteX` with changes *only* in the preamble?

The MWE below yields this output:

[image]

but I would like the title of the second to match the first without *any* changes *after* `\begin{document}`.

#### Possible Solution:

Another way to do this would to define my own environment with a key-value, but this would require that I implement in that environment *all* the possible `tcolorbox` options that I want to use and pass those onto `tcolorbox`.  I am hoping that there is a way to patch the `title`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{MyNoteX}[2][]{%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        title={Note:~#2},
        coltitle=black,
        colbacktitle=green!25,
        #1
        ]%
}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\newenvironment{MyNote}[1][]{%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        title={Note},
        coltitle=black,
        colbacktitle=orange!25,
        #1
        ]%
}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\pagecolor{white}
\begin{document}

\begin{MyNoteX}[]{My Title}
    This is produced by the \verb|MyNoteX| environment.
\end{MyNoteX}

\begin{MyNote}[title={My Title}]
    This is produced by the \verb|MyNote| environment.
    Title is \emph{not} correct.
\end{MyNote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Follow-up question: [Use of \noindent in a code={} of tcolorbox yields wacky vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689303/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See an update at the end of this answer...**

[image]

`tcolorbox` stores the title in `\kvtcb@title` after having evaluated the `title` key. One way to prepend a prefix is to use the `code` key and use `\pretocmd` from `etoolbox`, saying `\pretocmd{\kvtcb@title}{Note:~}{}{}`.

After Ulrike Fischer reminds me of the `before title` key, it is actually easier:

`before title={Note:~}`

This is shown in the special `mytitlebox` `tcolorbox` environment, which has one optional argument only and no 2nd mandatory argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newenvironment{MyNoteX}[2][]{%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        title={Note:~#2},
        coltitle=black,
        colbacktitle=green!25,
        #1
        ]%
}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\newenvironment{MyNote}[1][]{%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        title={Note},
        coltitle=black,
        colbacktitle=orange!25,
        #1,
        ]%
}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\makeatletter

\newtcolorbox{mytitlebox}[1][]{%
  nobeforeafter,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=orange!25,
  code={\noindent},
  before title={Note:~},
  #1,
}

\makeatother


\pagecolor{white}
\begin{document}

\begin{MyNoteX}[]{My Title}
    This is produced by the \verb|MyNoteX| environment.
\end{MyNoteX}

\begin{MyNote}[title={My Title}]
    This is produced by the \verb|MyNote| environment.
    Title is \emph{not} correct.
\end{MyNote}

\begin{mytitlebox}[title={My Title}]
  Foo
\end{mytitlebox}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

A variant that evaluates the title first and reinjects a `title=Note`, if there is no title first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newtcolorbox{mytitlebox}[1][]{%
  nobeforeafter,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=orange!25,
  code={\noindent\pgfkeysalsofiltered{#1}%
    \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\kvtcb@title}{\pgfkeysalsofiltered{title=Note}}{\pgfkeysalsofiltered{title=Note:~}}},
}

\makeatother


\pagecolor{white}
\begin{document}

\begin{mytitlebox}[title={My Title}]
  Foo
\end{mytitlebox}

\begin{mytitlebox}[colbacktitle={yellow!20}]
  Foo
\end{mytitlebox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: another way could be to redefine what `title=` does for `tcolorbox` options.

Comment: Do I miss something? Why don't you use the before title key?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Oh my... yes, I forgot about that... thanks, I've changed.

Comment: Well that was easy. Is it just as easy to default the _complete_ title to "Note" (without the colon) for the case where no title or `title={}` is provided.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Is that a question? ;-) Well, I suspect something like `before  title={Note\ifblank{\kvtcb@title}{}{:~}}` should work

Comment: Hmmm, can't seem to find the right combination to work as `title={}` suppresses the title bar altogther.  Will post a new question tomorrow if I can't figure it out in the morning

Comment: @PeterGrill: See the update at the bottom of my post

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Looks like the update broke the version where the title is specified. Using `title={My Title}` should produce the title `Note: My Title`, not just `Note:`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Oh, I missed that... I'll take a look

Comment: Easy fix: `code={\noindent\pgfkeysalsofiltered{#1}%
    \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\kvtcb@title}
        {\pgfkeysalsofiltered{title={Note}}}
        {\pgfkeysalsofiltered{before title={Note:~}}}%
  }`

Comment: @PeterGrill: I am pretty sure I had something similar in a previous version and wanted to be too clever and 'reduce' the code... I reduced too much. I will update with your proposition later on. Thanks.