# Use of \noindent in a code={} of tcolorbox yields wacky vertical spacing

Tags: tcolorbox, conditionals, frame-title

I adpated the `code={}` solution from [Auto append prefix to tcolorbox's title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473439/4301) to include a prefix to a title of a `tcolorbox` and was getting wacky spacing for a *subsequent* use of the `mytitlebox` environment (see spacing before box 2).

Turns out this is resolved if I remove the `\noindent` (as is done prior to box 3).

[image]

While this resolves the test case, it does not resolve the problem in my actual use case, so I hoping the understanding this issue may help me locate my actual problem.

#### Question:

Why is the `\noindent` a problem in a subsequent use of `mytitlebox`, but fine for the first use of `mytitlebox`.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagecolor{white}

\newcommand{\NoIndent}{\noindent}% So we can disable this in the test case.

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{mytitlebox}[1][]{%
  %%nobeforeafter,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=orange!25,
  %% Adapted from
  %%    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473438/auto-append-prefix-to-tcolorboxs-title
  code={%
    \NoIndent% <-- works fine if this if commented
    \pgfkeysalsofiltered{#1}%
    \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\kvtcb@title}%
        {\pgfkeysalsofiltered{title=Note}}%
        {\pgfkeysalsofiltered{before title=Note:~}}%
  },
  #1,
}
\makeatother


\pagecolor{white}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text before box 1.
\begin{mytitlebox}[title={My Title 1}, colbacktitle={cyan!20}]
  Text in box.
\end{mytitlebox}

Text after box 1 and before box 2.

\begin{mytitlebox}[title={My Title 2}, colbacktitle={green!20}]
  Text in box.
\end{mytitlebox}

Text after box 2 and before box 3, but with \verb|\def\NoIndent{}|
\def\NoIndent{}%

\begin{mytitlebox}[title={My Title 3}, colbacktitle={orange!20}]
  Text in box.
\end{mytitlebox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well the difference between 1 and 2 is that you have a blank line before the second box and so a paragraph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ok, but still a little confused. It seems that if I add a blank line to indicate a paragrph brea, this results in no paragraph break, but removing the blank to indicate no paragraph break, yields a paragraph?

Comment: tcolorbox has in various places code where spaces are inserting depending on `\lastnodetype`, and with your lonely `\noindent` before the box you are changing these tests.